# Symfony2 get parameters.yml in entity, special case

Tags: symfony

I know its against the framework to make an entity container aware, but this is a special case, i have a credit card entity, and i want to do this:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNumber()
{
    $number = $this->number;
    $crypt = base64_decode($number);
    $number = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return trim($number);
}

/**
 * @param $number
 * @return $this
 */
public function setNumber($number)
{
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $number, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $number = trim(base64_encode($crypt));
    $this->number = $number;
    return $this;
}
```

And i want the $key to be the secret from parameters.yml, since i dont want to save it in the code.

I can't pass it as a parameter, when i use the FormType, cause the form type will not pass it when it binds the request.

```
    $credit_card = new CreditCard();
    $credit_card->setCustomer($customer);
    $payment_form = $this->createPaymentForm($credit_card);

    $payment_form->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: You should try using the built-in `Event` dispatcher with a `prePersist` event for example, for this entity alone.

Comment: I'm guessing you are instantiating the CreditCard on a controller so you should be able to access the container there and set parameters into the CreditCard

`$credit_card->setEncryptionKey($this->getParameter('secretkey'));`

And then accesing that parameter from inside the CreditCard entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove data modifications from your Entity, and add it to your FormType.

```
public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->number;
}

public function setNumber($number)
{
    $this->number = $number;

    return $this;
}
```

Make your `FormType` take the parameter as argument.

```
class CreditCardType extends AbstractType {

    private $key;

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    // ...

    // Listen on the PRE_BIND event to update your value before binding
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (FormEvent $event) 
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $number = $data['number'];
        $crypt = $this->encryptNumber($number);
        $data['number'] = $crypt;

        $event->setData($data);
    });

    public function encryptNumber($key, $number)
    {
        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $number, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $number = trim(base64_encode($crypt));

        return $number;    
    }
}
```

Now, in your createPaymentForm, add the parameter to your `FormType` instance, like this :

```
$param = $this->container->getParameter('yourkeyparam'); 
$form = $this->createForm(new CreditCardType($param), $credit_card, array());
```

Hope this is what you need.